# Spark-java redirect - browser does not redirect

Tags: http, redirect, single-page-application, http-redirect, spark-java

Ok, so I try to follow Spark documentation and I want to perform simple redirect in my Single Page Application. My code looks like this:

```
post("/users/login", (req, res) -> {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        User creation = mapper.readValue(req.body(), User.class);
        User user = userService.getUser(creation.getLogin());
        if (user.getPassword().equals(creation.getPassword())) {
            req.session().attribute("userid", creation.getLogin());
            System.out.println("OK");
            res.status(201);
            res.redirect("/index.html");
            return "";
        }
        System.out.println("BAD");
        return null;
    } , json());
```

Basically, I have three static html files: registration.html, login.html and index.html. I read stuff concerning staticFileLocation so I added at the beginning of main function following line of code:

```
staticFileLocation("/public");
```

When I type correct login and password I find in the network view in Chrome that I have GET request with status 200, OK, to http://localhost:4567/index.html. However, the browser does nothing and does not redirect me to that page. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here's javascript code that handles log in on the client side:

```
app.controller('LoginUserCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.loginUser = {};
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'http://localhost:4567/users/login',
        data : $scope.loginUser,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }).success(function() {
        console.log("User logged successfully");
        console.log($scope.loginUser);
    }).error(function() {
        console.log("Unknown error while logging user");
    });

};
});
```

Comment: I would like to add that when I send post I get status 302 and then GET request with status 200 but still browser (I tried Chrome and IE) does nothing...

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that you're redirecting to an HTML page in a post endpoint that's supposed to return Json data. You have to return a single json if authentication succeeded or failed, like `{"auth": "OK"}` or `{"auth": "NOK"}`, and decide where to redirect to from Javascript based in it's information.

Comment: But why can't I do so? This post is only to catch login and password and if it matches login and password stored in collection I just want to load new page. I can't understand why I get a page I want in network tab in Chrome with status GET 200 but the browser does nothing.

Comment: Single Page Applications follow a diferent approach. What you were intending to do was a full load of a new page, that would not be appropriate. I could explain better if you post your Javascript (or whatever client side language you're using) code that does the post request to /users/login. Could you update your question with it ?

Comment: Sure, I put it in question body. I am building a simple application in the browser which task is to do something, but first I need to log in to get to this page.

Comment: Your callbacks to success and error must declare a parameter, something like  `}).success(function(res) {`. The res parameter will contain information about the response, including http status and a `res.data` attribute, which is the json response from your server. Then, based on this response, you can redirect to the desired page, in AngularJS you can use the location service for that, like `$location.path('/index')`

Comment: Do I really have to modify client side code? Following Spark documentation I don't understand why res.redirect doesn't redirect me to wanted page.

Comment: Just take declare the parameter in your success callback and debug it in your browser (F12 on Chrome). Put a breakpoint inside your success callback and see the res object's properties. You'll get it. Server redirection is not a good choice for Single Page Apps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions however from different reasons I have to use server redirection and I want to understand why my code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It's because res.redirect will send a redirect http header(HTTP status values 301, 302, 303 and 307) to the browser,

but the browser only can redirect in `get`, NOT work in `post` or `put` or `delete` (Tested in chrome. Notice that a redirect request was sent by browser, but the page just not change...).

See:

http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/post-redirect.html